# Why does DynamoDB stream trigger but the entry is not in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am using DynamoDB as my database and have DynamoDB streams setup to do some extra things when a row is saved onto DynamoDB.

But my problem is that when i write to a database. The dynamo stream is getting triggered but when i try to fetch the data from the lambda that is triggered by the stream the event is not present in the dynamo table.

Really not sure why it is happening. Is it something that happens when the table gets big and we try to add a lot of data in dynamo at the same time?

I have a combination of partition key and sort key. partition key is the userId and sort key is the timestamp. Could it be something due to that?

Could it be that the entries are lot of a lot of different services try to write to dynamo at the same time?

Comment: May be due to consistency, for testing purposes have you tried adding a short wait of like a few seconds into the lambda before it tries to retrieve the item?

Comment: the problem is if i try to find the id again by querying dynamo manually, it will still not be present is the table.

Comment: I have a combination of partition key and sort key. partition key is the userId and sort key is the timestamp. Could it be something due to that? @luk2302

Comment: It sounds like you aren't doing a strongly-consistent read. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html What are you trying to do exactly? If you just need the new record, it should be passed into the Lambda event so you don't need to query the DB for it.

Comment: @MarkB I am using a dynamo table as a eventstore. So it has more than 200k records. Anytime a data is written to eventstore, i have a dynamo stream that calls on a lambda function which adds a message to sqs. And to add data to sqs, thje the lambda queries the dynamo table. But the lambda is not able to find the entry

Comment: OK, so fix your code to do a strongly consistent read. It's been mentioned multiple times in the comments here. Show your code if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks ill try that and see if that solves my problem

Comment: But i was not able to find a entry for what was causing the error in dynamo when i searched it from the AWS console. So not sure if that will help

Comment: It still sounds like the lambda is querying the db only for the entry that triggered it. If that is the case as @MarkB pointed out you don't need to query the db. The entry is in the triggering event.

Comment: Wouldn't triggers make it easier by having the payload provided?

Comment: @hunterhacker I just had added that check to confirm the data is in the database. But for some reason the data is not stored in the database but the stream is triggered.

Comment: @MarkB I tried consistent but seems that also doesnot solve the issue

Comment: With triggers the item will be pushed to your lambda and you can trust that it's in the database if it's been pushed. If you don't believe it's not there when you ask, either it's because you're using eventual consistency or you've got an odd bug in your code.

Comment: why dont you share your code so that everyone can guide you better?